What is the category of mixed multigraphs?
I’m aware that we can regard (simple) directed graphs and (simple) undirected graphs as objects in categories whose morphisms are suitably defined graph homomorphisms. Likewise, there are well-known categories of multigraphs (allowing multiple edges between the same vertices) and pseudo-graphs (allowing loops, multiple edges, etc.).
However, I’m trying to figure out the correct way to organize mixed multigraphs—graphs that allow both directed and undirected edges (and possibly multiple edges of either type)—into a category. More explicitly:

Objects: A mixed multigraph should consist of:

A set of vertices (V).
A set of edges (E), each of which is either:

Undirected: connecting two (not necessarily distinct) vertices in an unordered way (allowing loops and multiple edges).
Directed: connecting two vertices in an ordered way (again, allowing loops and multiple edges).




Morphisms: What is the most standard or natural choice for morphisms between mixed multigraphs?
A few possibilities come to mind:

A function on vertices $f \colon V_1 \to V_2$ such that edges are sent to edges in a way compatible with their “mixed” nature. For example, if $(u,v)$ is a directed edge in the source, its image should be a directed edge $(f(u), f(v))$ in the target; likewise for undirected edges $\{u,v\}$.
Possibly we also require that parallel edges “map” in a consistent way. But do we allow identification (i.e., multiple edges in the source mapping to a single edge in the target)? Or do we require a strict preservation of the multiedge structure?
Is there a standard reference or consensus in the literature on the “free” vs. “faithful” approaches to morphisms for mixed multigraphs?


Composition: Once the morphisms are pinned down, composition should just be the usual composition of vertex-maps that also respects the induced mapping of edges.


I’d really appreciate guidance on which version of morphism one typically uses to get a well-behaved category. Also, if there’s a known name (“the category of mixed multigraphs with X-homomorphisms,” etc.) or standard reference for it, I’d love to hear it.
Thank you!

What’s a directed loop? How can a vertex be connected to itself "in an ordered way"?

@joriki A directed loop is a directed edge whose source and target are the same vertex. You have an ordered pair (v,v). Even though it starts and ends at the same place, it’s still considered “directed” because we keep track of the source and target roles (even if they coincide).

@joriki You may ask why we distinguish them if both map to loops. Indeed, under a morphism, loop maps to loop. But the structure we preserve differs: a directed loop (v,v) encodes a self-arrow with distinct in/out roles, whereas an undirected loop {v,v} is just a single-endpoint edge. Category theory cares about whether direction is preserved or ignored, so it treats these loops differently.

You'll have a category of categories which are graphs.  In the undirected case, each connected pair of vertices is in isomorphism.  If you don't want identity maps always / necessarily, then what you have is a Semi-category (category minus identity axiom).   Anyway, I would say what is your definition of "structure preserving?"  If each object is itself a category, the most natural is always gonna be functor, otherwise you may be shooting yourself in the foot.

Btw, there's a way to define commutativity for diagrams which are not forming a DAG skeleton.  Using regexes of course!  One between any pair of objects in the diagram.   These regexes are then the class of equivalent paths.

If the distinction between undirected and directed edges is important, perhaps it is best to encode it into the structure from the start. So a graph would consist of a set $V$ of vertices, together with two sets $E_0$ and $E_1$ and maps $s,t: E_1 \to V$ and $d: E_0 \to {{V}\choose{2}}\cup {{V}\choose{1}}$. A morphism from $G$ to $G'$ then consists of maps $f: V\to V'$, $f_i; E_i\to E'_i$ compatible with the structure maps.
